# return multiple numbers from the loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to create a function that returns 50 random numbers out of 100. If I write console.log(getMines), it returns all fifty numbers. But if I want to actually use them, my loop returns only one number. What's the problem?

```
var getMines = function() {
    for (count; count <= 100; count++) {
        return "d" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50));
    }
}
```

Comment: The "problem" is, that `return` stops the execution of the current function, totally.

Comment: You should use an array and push the random numbers into that array

Comment: _"my loop returns only one number"_.. Looks like your question has the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only return a single value from a function. So once you return your first number, the loop essentially ends.

Try this instead!

```
var getMines = function() {
    var minesArray = [];
    for (var count=0; count <= 100; count++) {
        minesArray.push("d" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)));
    }
    return minesArray;
}
```

This will return an array of all the numbers, which you can then iterate through to do what you need. You can sort the numbers, or sum them etc.

I feel I should point out that your code is returning 100 random numbers between 1 and 50, not 50 random numbers between 1 and 100. If thats what you want and you misspoke in the OP nbd, but if you want 50 random numbers between 1 and 100 change count to <= 50 and multiply Math.random() by 100 instead.

Comment: Maybe you need add the correction to `for (count; count <= 100;`, `for (var count = 0; count <= 100;`, or is not neccesary ?

Comment: Dude, thank you very much. I want to be as smart as you! Where did you learn javaScript?

Comment: Haha you will get it in time mate, it's really just a matter of practice. I learned a lot from freecodecamp and hackerrank so those are worth checking out. No matter what though, just code as much as you can! Any coding is productive coding. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You need create a var and push randoms, like this

```
var getMines = function() {
    var returnArray = [];
    for (var count = 0; count <= 100; count++) {
        returnArray.push("d" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)));
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can only return only once from a function, you can use an array or object, add all values to it and return it.

```
var getMines = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for (count; count <= 100; count++) {
        arr.push("d" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)));
    }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I read you question right, you need 50 numbers with a random value out of 100.

You need to switch the numbers in the `for` loop and the factor for getting a random number and take a initial value of zero for the looping variable, as well as not return some value inside of the `for` loop.

```js
var getMines = function() {
    var count,
        array = [];

    for (count = 0; count < 50; count++) {
        array.push("d" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));
    }

    return array;
}

console.log(getMines());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

That can also be done with some cool ES6 tricks:

```
const getMines = ()=> Array.from(
   {length:50},
   ()=> "d" + Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 )
);
```

Comment: With ES6 is better use a function generator

Comment: @kip you mean a generator function? And no, thats not better.

Comment: In this case to get all values, is not a better option, but maybe in arrays random with a huge size is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you need any random 50 numbers between 1 and 100 (both inclusive, I have tweaked your version to following. See if that helps.

```js
 var getMines = function() {
        var nums = [];
        for (var count=1; count <= 50; count++) {
            nums[count-1]=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        }
        return nums;
    }
    console.log(getMines());
```